# R - How to copy and paste files from one location to another within an s3 bucket (using aws.s3)?

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I want to copy a file from one directory to another within the same S3 bucket using the `aws.s3` package in R. I have tried the following code, but it is throwing an error.

```
library(aws.s3)
Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = Sys.getenv('AWS_KEY'),
           AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = Sys.getenv('AWS_SECRET'),
           AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "us-west-2")

old_path <- 's3://bucket_name/some_folder/filename.avro'
new_path <- paste0(strsplit(old_path, 'bucket_name')[[1]][1],
                   'bucket_name/old_data',
                   strsplit(old_path, 'bucket_name')[[1]][2])

copy_object(from_object = old_path,
            to_object = new_path,
            from_bucket = 'bucket_name',
            to_bucket = 'bucket_name')
```

Here is the error -

```
- Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404)`.
```

I am able to run commands like `bucket_exists`, which means that I am able to connect to AWS.

Comment: You are repeating the bucket in the `from_object` and `to_object` entries. Instead, these should just be the portion of the object name following the slash after the bucket name. So, in your case, these should be `from_object = /some_folder/filename.avro` and `to_object = old_data/some_folder/filename.avro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `copy_object` method doesn't work for some reason, but I was able to get the following code to do the same thing -

```
put_object(get_object(old_path, 'bucket_name'), new_path, 'bucket_name')
```

And then if you want to delete the old file -

```
delete_object(old_path, 'bucket_name')
```

Comment: This works because `put_bucket`, `get_object` allow using 'S3 URI' syntax (the full object 'path' like s3://example_bucket/example_folder/file.name.avro). I expect the function must ignore the bucket name in those cases. The documentation for delete_object does not explicitly say it allows S3 URIs, but if it worked for you, maybe it does.

Answer (score 0):

Object keys in S3 do not begin with a leading `/` (that's the root of the bucket, not the first character of the object key) but many libraries *incorrecty* allow you to start an object key with the character `/` and have things still work as you expect with calls like GetObject.  This is unfortunate, but by now, it's entrenched in a lot of places (including at least some of the official SDKs), so it's difficult to repair without causing widespread problems.

But... because of the way S3's PUT+Copy API works on the wire, libraries that "help" you by silently swallowing the incorrect leading `/` from an object key on most operations (e.g. GetObject) may fail to work their same erroneous magic on CopyObject operations, and fail if you pass an object key beginning with `/`.  When this happens, it is the fault of the library authors, not the S3 service.

Verify that your `old_path` does **not** begin with a `/` and the `copy_object()` operation should work as expected.  There is an important difference between doing that and doing what you are doing -- `copy_object()` should be using S3's internal copy operation, which avoids download and re-upload, with the entire operation actually occuring inside of S3.

Comment: Well my old path is the following - `s3://bucket_name/some_folder/filename.avro`. It is not beginning with a `/` in this case. What would you say I should change my old path to?

Comment: Yes, I misread your code.  You almost certainly *should* be setting `old_path` to simply `some_folder/filename.avro` (and I incorrectly thought you were setting it to `/some_folder/filename.avro` which is why I made reference to the leading slash).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Apparently my syntax was correct, but the file location address was too long for R to parse. It worked when I reduced the subfolders that I had to go through.